# efecto toggle con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy intentando pasar un viejo componente que solía tener escrito en vanillaJS a react para agregar a un nuevo proyecto, el mismo en si es muy sencillo.

Consiente dos `input` uno de tipo `range` y otro de tipo `checkbox` y dos `h1` que van cambiando dependiendo de los eventos que suceden en los input.
Por ejemplo cuando muevo el `input` de tipo `range`, este dispara una función que cambia el valor de los dos `h1`, a su tiempo se fija si el `input` de tipo `checkbox` esta `checked`, en caso que sea `true` se le resta un 25% al valor del `h1` en caso contrario sigue todo igual.

El problema esta en que una vez que hago click sobre el `checkbox` este si realiza el descuento sobre el valor del `price` pero el valor de `price` vuelve a su estado inicial y la barra del `range` vuelve al 50.

me surgen varias maneras de solucionar esto, podría ser usando un el `useEffect` ?

Aqui pueden ver en funcionamiento el codigo : [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-glade-uj0ec?file=/src/App.js:69-1538)

Este seria el código del componente:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(8);
  const [plan, setPlan] = useState("10k");
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const handleDiscount = () => {
    setToggle((toggle) => !toggle);
  };

  const handlePriceChange = (e) => {
    const valueChange = e.target.value;
    setValue(valueChange);
    let pricing = 8;
    if ((value > 0) & (value <= 20)) {
      setPlan("10k");
      pricing = 8;
    } else if (value > 20 && value <= 40) {
      setPlan("50k");
      pricing = 12;
    } else if (value > 40 && value <= 60) {
      setPlan("100k");
      pricing = 16;
    } else if (value > 60 && value <= 80) {
      setPlan("500k");
      pricing = 24;
    } else if (value > 80 && value <= 100) {
      setPlan("1M");
      pricing = 36;
    }

    if (toggle === true) {
      setPrice(pricing - pricing * 0.25);
    } else {
      setPrice(pricing);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="range"
        name="range"
        value={value}
        min="0"
        max="100"
        className="slider"
        id="range"
        onChange={handlePriceChange}
      />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="discount"
        className="discount"
        id="discount"
        onClick={handleDiscount}
        onChange={handlePriceChange}
      />
      <> {price} </>
      <hr />
      <> {plan} Pageviews </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Y este es el código original en vanillaJS:

```js
const range = document.getElementById('range');
const pageviewsCount = document.getElementById('pageviews-count');
const toggleDiscount = document.getElementById('toggle_discount');
const price = document.getElementById('price');

function handlePricingChanges(value) {
    let pricing = 8;

    if ((value > 0) & (value <= 20)) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '10K Pageviews';
        pricing = 8;
    } else if (value > 20 && value <= 40) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '50K Pageviews';
        pricing = 12;
    } else if (value > 40 && value <= 60) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '100K Pageviews';
        pricing = 16;
    } else if (value > 60 && value <= 80) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '500K Pageviews';
        pricing = 24;
    } else if (value > 80 && value <= 100) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '1M Pageviews';
        pricing = 36;
    }

    if (toggleDiscount.checked) {
        const totalValue = pricing - pricing * 0.25;
        price.textContent = `$${totalValue}.00`;
    } else {
        price.textContent = `$${pricing}.00`;
    }


}

range.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    console.log('range value :>> ', event.target.value);
    const value = range.value;
    handlePricingChanges(value);
});

toggleDiscount.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    console.log('range value :>> ', event.target.value);
    const value = range.value;
    handlePricingChanges(val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que falta decirle a React que controle el componente `checkbox`, esto se hace mapeando el valor de la propiedad de estado `value`, en la propiedad `value` del `checkbox`:

```js
    function App() {
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
      const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(8);
      const [plan, setPlan] = React.useState("10k");
      const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);

      const handleDiscount = () => {
        setToggle((toggle) => !toggle);
      };

      const handlePriceChange = (e) => {
        const valueChange = e.target.value;
        console.log("type: ",e.target.type);
        console.log("valueChange: ",valueChange)
        setValue(valueChange);
        //logica
      };

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input
            type="range"
            name="range"
            value={value}
            min="0"
            max="100"
            id="range"
            onChange={handlePriceChange}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="discount"
            id="discount"
            value={value}
            onClick={handleDiscount}
            onChange={handlePriceChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="discount">discount</label>
          <div> {price} </div>
          <hr />
          <div> {plan} Pageviews </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
     
     
     ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

    <div id="root"></div>
```

Así como se encuentra el [proyecto](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-glade-uj0ec?file=/src/App.js:69-1538), el `checkbox` no tiene asignada la propiedad `value`, por lo cual le asigna un valor [ON por default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value), y ese valor es el que se asigna a la propiedad de estado `value`, dentro de la función `handlePriceChange`, cuando se llama desde el `checkbox`.

Por esta razón, la barra de `range` se comporta de forma inestable, recíbe `On` en vez de un rango numerico.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.